# Javascript bookmarklet with image on github readme

Tags: javascript, github, bookmarklet, github-flavored-markdown

I'm having troubles adding a javascript bookmarklet with an image to my github readme. The image is supposed to make it easy for the user to add the bookmark to his bookmarkbar.

Basically [this (http://alaingilbert.github.com/Turntable-API/bookmarklet.html)](http://alaingilbert.github.com/Turntable-API/bookmarklet.html) is what I'm trying to achieve but instead on a github readme.

So far I have this:

```
<table style="border: none;">

  <tbody>

    <tr style="border:none;">

      <td style="vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 10px; border: none;">

        <a href="javascript:(function(){ window.open(‘http://www.test.com/’); })();">

          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCSDi.png">

        </a>

      </td>

      <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; border: none;">

        ← Drag this to your bookmark bar.

      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

But when I look at the sourcecode of my readme on github I notice that the href attribute seems to have gone, so the bookmarklet won't work anymore.

Does github remove javascript href's automatically? Is there a way to fix this problem?

Edit: the attributes from table, tbody, tr and td tags seem to be gone as well. Seems like github doesn't like them?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
                                             v                    v
<a href="javascript:(function(){ window.open(‘http://www.test.com/’); })();">
                                             ^                    ^
```

To this:

```
                                             v                    v
<a href="javascript:(function(){ window.open('http://www.test.com/'); })();">
                                             ^                    ^
```

The quotes you're currently using aren't valid Javascript quote delimiters

EDIT: DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/BXn9Z/

Comment: I know it should work that way. But it's that github is stripping the tags from its attributes when pushing a new README.md

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this: [Embed Bookmarklet in GitHub README.md](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314567).
There is also the correct answer. It is not possible to make a bookmarklet available from github repo readme. Instead, you can use github pages.