# Embed Bookmarklet in GitHub README.md

Tags: javascript, github, markdown

Was trying to put in a Bookmarklet in a Github README.md. But, the following markdown code fails:

`[Bookmarklet](javascript:alert('not-working'))`

From the compiled output it seems javascript in the link seems to be stripped off. Can anyone confirm whether this is a policy for Github pages? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Embedding JavaScript is disabled to prevent Cross-Site Scripting.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for confirming. Somehow, couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to handle this? I need a site that can host a javascript bookmarklet.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up custom pages:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually

Then you can navigate to them via:

```
http://<username>.github.io/<project>/<filepath>
```